# External Javascript file not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

This is extremely basic but I'm unsure why this has stopped working. I have the following html file

```
<html>
<!doctype html>
<head>
  
   <script> document.write("this is working")</script>
   <p>this is working</p>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the following javascript file that is in the same folder as the html file

```
document.write("Hello World!");
```

The scripts and html within the html document work fine. However, the external javascript file does not get executed. I have tried with a variety of scripts in the js file and minor modifications to the html file. On a windows 10 computer.

Note this is not a repeated question, the other questions similar to this one were slightly different.

EDIT: Error in browser console states "not allowed to load local source"
This may be a chrome security issue.
EDIT: Same case in all browsers so doesn't seem purely related to chrome. Attempted all the fixes I could find but did not work.

EDIT: I tried using both node and python for the server.

Comment: Hi ! Which server do you use on Windows 10 ? `XAMPP` ?

Comment: @Philippe Using express right now, tried regular http in case that was the problem as well though.

Comment: Two things: it seems like you are not opening the `html` tag before `<head>`. Fix it. Second: is the JavaScript file in the same directory of the HTML file?

Comment: @Diego yes it is, and yes I just copied from line 2 accidentally. Fixed the question.

Comment: `<!doctype html>` comes before `<html>`. Anyway, I don't think someone can help you without further details. If possible, please hit `CTRL + SHIFT + J` in your browser to open the console, and check what the error message says. Then it will be much easier to debug.

Comment: @Diego "not allowed to load local source"

Comment: To be honest I never really faced this problem, but if you are using Chrome, this looks like a Chrome's security issue. Please refer to this [link](https://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/windows.html), I believe it may solve your problem.

Comment: @Diego unfortunately that did not work either.

Comment: Does it need a type attribute? `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: @ShanerM13 doesn't change the result.

Comment: Never use `document.write` - [it is not of this era. Or the previous one](https://pomax.github.io/1473270609919/if-you-use-use-document-write-you-suck-at-javascript). Use normal modern JS at the very least, load it in the `<head>`, and use the `async` and `defer` attributes on your script element.

Comment: Also note that the doctype comes before the html tag, and that you can't put a `<p>` in the head element. So, really, it might be time to first read a few tutorials about writing HTML pages, because there's just _a lot_ wrong here

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans none of that is relevant to the issue at hand. Please don't speak at all if you have no useful information.

Comment: You said you are using node? I've had a similar problem with django not serving my javascript and css files... I'm trying to remember what I did to solve that...

Comment: @ShanerM13 tried both node and python.

Comment: @daredevil that's not how this site works: if there are things wrong with your code, you should expect people to point all of it out. and if you don't want people to highlight things that are very obviously being done wrong, then this is not the right place for you to ask for help. Putting `<p>` outside the body is a fundamental error in writing HTML, and if that's the kind of mistakes that are being made, the very first step is to (re)learn how to write proper HTML, because that's just going to keep causing problems until it's done right.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're loading the HTML file through file protocol (i.e. double-clicking the file and opening it in a browser). In that case, browser may deny to load any external resources (`test.js` script in your case) due to security. Load the HTML through HTTP protocol. It can be achieved numerous ways.

- If you have **PHP** installed, simply running `php -S localhost:80` within the project directory will spin up a local server, which you can browse by visiting `http://localhost`. It will then serve the `index.html` page by default.
- If you have **Node.js** installed (thus `npm`, too), install `http-server` globally (`npm i http-server -g`). And afterthat, run `http-server` within the project directory. By default, it will spin up a local server on port `8080`, so you'll be able to visit `http://localhost:8080` and `index.html` will be served.

I tried the later one, and your above code worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I was running it through node (as stated in the comments above). So no, that does not solve the issue.

Comment: Then something's wrong in other place(s). Your code works fine, apart from what Mike suggested you in [his](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69592610/external-javascript-file-not-working-in-html/69593087#comment123009034_69592610) comment. It'd be even better if you can provide a minimum reproduction repo, so that we can replicate what you're facing right now.

Answer (score -3):

This is not a solution, but it is a work around if anyone has the same issue and a better answer is not produced.

Get the chrome extension "web server" and open that rather than running it through node, python, etc.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30092274)

Comment: @tacoshy since I am the author, no, it does provide a useful enough answer to the question and may help other people who find it.

Comment: this is not how SO works. recommending tools within an answer can be considered advertisement and as such is forbidden. Your question went through a review. This answer was genereted automatically.

Comment: @tacoshy there are plenty of other answers that recommend tools. This tool was even specifically mentioned as an answer to other questions, so I fail to see your logic.